# Auto-populating a form from an e-mail link

Tags: forms, email, auto-populate

I'm looking to send out emails containing links to sites that dynamically pre-populate the form fields.

I've been using form field ID's with the link like so

http://website.com/sub/orders.php?Name=Joe&email=fake@faker.com

but it doesn't seem to be working, any ideas?

Comment: This can be done but it requires coding in the form, and you haven't said which language it's coded in.

Comment: I'm coding in HTML and PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing this in PHP, you'd need something like ...

```
if (isset($_GET['email'])) {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
}
else {
    $email = '';
}
```

...

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="'.$email.'">
```

Basically, you need to pull in the get variable to prepopulate the form.

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to add this right now, thanks a lot!